# How to repair scruffed sides of a hardback book cover?

Tags: book-binding, restoration

How do you repair scruffed sides of a hardback book cover? Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: book cover]

Comment: What do you mean by repair? Wouldn't the book need to be rebound?

Comment: Take a course in book-binding. Really: if you want to do this properly, you are going to have to learn it properly. In this specific case, I think you're going to need to replace the cover entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get them covered by another binding (a cute paper or inverted blank side of the paper of a calendar) or seal the edges with transparent scotch  tape (half inside of the cover, and half outside) to prevent it from further fraying.